# m2eclipse weblogic-maven-plugin Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001': invalid type code: 31

Tags: m2eclipse, weblogic9.x, helios

I'm trying to deploy a web application to weblogic server installed in my local machine. It works well when mvn install is invoked from command line. However from eclipse, it gives the error - "Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001': invalid type code: 31."

Weblogic list apps beginning with parameters DeployMojoBase[adminServerHostName = localhost, adminServerProtocol = http, adminServerPort = 7001, userId = weblogic, password = weblogic, projectPackaging = war, name = miadidas-ecom-1, targetNames = AdminServer, remote = false]

An error occurred in phase mojoExecution with the exception org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Exception encountered during artifact listapps: weblogic.deploy.api.tools.deployer.DeployerException: Unable to connect to 'http://localhost:7001': invalid type code: 31. Ensure the url represents a running admin server and that the credentials are correct. If using http protocol, tunneling must be enabled on the admin server.

Answer (score 1):

enable HTTP tunneling in WebLogic Server if you havent already done so, Go to Administration Console at Environment > Servers > AdminServer > Protocols > HTTP and set Enable Tunneling= true.

if tunneling is enabled, you can change [http://localhost:7001] by [t3://localhost:7001]

if you are getting this after enabling tunneling use following option to execute all the tasks
-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true